# Does the map of India using 'india_map <- map_data("world", region = "India")' contain Kashmir as part of it?

Tags: r

What is the best way to pinpoint the exact places in the map of India using india_map <- map_data("world", region = "India") code?

Comment: this isn't a programming question, it's a political question. Also, your description question is different to the title question

Answer (score 2):

The literal question:

> Does the map of India ... contain Kashmir as part of it?

I think the answer is **somewhat**, though I claim no expertise here.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir) lists Kashmir as

> *Today, the term encompasses a larger area that includes the India-administered territories of Jammu and Kashmir and Ladakh, the Pakistan-administered territories of Azad Kashmir and Gilgit-Baltistan, and the Chinese-administered territories of Aksai Chin and the Trans-Karakoram Tract.*
> [image: low-res image of Kashmir from Wiki]

(Click on the link to see a higher-resolution image. The image is a reduced screenshot of the full image, too large for the Stack interface size restrictions; screenshot taken on 2023-07-27.)

The description suggests the Kashmir *region* encompasses land under Pakistan, India, and China territory. I believe the India-portion of that land is included in the world-data of `maps` for India.

```r
ggplot(map_data("world", c("Pakistan", "India")), aes(long, lat)) + 
  coord_quickmap() +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data=subset(maps::world.cities, name == "Pathankot"), color="red")
```

[image: maps plot including Pakistan, India, and a red dot for Pathankot]

The red dot represents the city of Pathankot, which the wiki image depicts as just south of the southern border of the Kashmir region (I included the city solely for a visual reference point). Visually comparing the ggplot boundary north of that red point with the wiki image, it appears that the `maps` data includes much of Kashmir but does not appear to include Azad Kashmir, which appears to be included in the Pakistan map data.

Caveats:

- I am not a cartographer, and inferring that the `maps` data is geopolitically accurate is likely an unsafe assumption.
- Nor am I an expert in geopolitical definitions of Kashmir, the Kashmir Valley, Kashmir region, etc.
- There are many ways to plot world data, I chose the simplest to try to deliver my point. Perhaps there are other map databases that provide *boundaries* for the Kashmir region(s), but that wasn't your question (and I do not know off-hand a good reference for it, though a hasty search for `CRAN maps India` suggested https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/expectreg/html/india.bnd.html).